# Does typescript baseUrl flag override the resolution mechanism of moduleResolution: node?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I've red the official doc of module resolution in [moduleResolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). We use `--moduleResolution` to set the resolution method and we recommand use `node` method which will find non-relative modules in `node_modules` dirs up from current dir.

But the doc also mentiones [an additional module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#additional-module-resolution-flags) which will find non-relative modules in the dir specified by `baseUrl`.

So does it mean that if we set `baseUrl`, the module resolution process will totally ignore `node_modules` dirs?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question - ***Yes***, the module resolution process will ignore `node_modules` folder and non-relative names will be assumed to be relative to the `baseUrl`.

But note that using a `baseUrl` is a common practice in applications using `AMD` module loaders where modules are “deployed” to a `single folder` at run-time.

If that `single folder` does not contain the `non-relative` modules like for example in some cases you want these libraries to be present in specific folders, then you have to use the [`path-mapping`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) to resolve the issues.

For example if you are using `moment` library and it is placed in specific directory under root folder which your modules are looking for it, then you have to explicitly mention the path something like below in tsconfig.json file -

```
"baseUrl": "." ,
"paths": {
      "moment": ["node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    },
```

For `non-absolute` module resolution see [`here`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl) -

But generally if you are writing a new application using node then use "`commonjs`" modules instead `AMD` modules.

Comment: So after setting `baseUrl`,  if we want to use some module in node_modules, we must list it in `paths` mapping?

Comment: Yes - all non-relative names will be assumed to be relative to the baseUrl! I tried the same in my local debugging POC.

Comment: I tested and found that it was NOT like what you said. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

I tested and found the answer:

**If baseUrl is set, typescript will use it(along with `paths`) to resolve a module first. But if the resolution failed, it will go to `node_modules` as usual**

Take `import React from 'react'` as example(`--traceResolution`):

[image]

Comment: This only seems to work if moduleResolution is explicitly set to "node" in tsconfig.json - for anyone who isn't seeing the intended behavior, try setting it!